# Is it possible to directly work on correlation matrix in Stata?

Tags: correlation, stata

I am new to Stata, and I have a 12X12 correlation matrix as my input. I want to perform a confirmatory factor analysis on the variables in this data. I see that sem is the command to perform this.

But I do not know how Stata will recognise my data as a correlation matrix, instead of as 12-variables and 12-observations. Is there a way either at the input or at sem command to specify this?

Comment: Since this question is just about how to do something in Stata, I marked it for migration to StackOverflow

Comment: Have you checked "intro 10 — Fitting models using summary statistics data" of Stata's SEM manual (sem.pdf)? Type in -help sem- and then click on "[SEM] sem -- Introduction to structural equation modeling"

Comment: If you imported your correlations as variables and needed to convert to a matrix first, see the `svmat` command.